# Cocoa Touch Framework with CocoaPods dependencies

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, frameworks

I'm trying to create a **Cocoa Touch Framework**.

- I created a Cocoa Touch Framework
- I ran `pod init`
- I added our own CocoaPod to this, which has some dependencies itself as well.
- I ran `pod install`.

Now when I try to build the framework (I open the `.xcodeproj`) I get the following warnings for each dependency.

> ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/jeroen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/OurFramework-culynvrparvtfjbjlitmammotpkf/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Alamofire'

I get the following errors:

> ld: framework not found Alamofire
>   error: Resource "/Users/jeroen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/OurFramework-culynvrparvtfjbjlitmammotpkf/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/FirebaseFirestore/gRPCCertificates-Firestore.bundle" not found. Run 'pod install' to update the copy resources script.

I expect that this is because the CocoaPod files are not copied to the right place. Is that correct?
What could I do to make this work anyway?

The reason I want to do this is the following:
I have a CocoaPods project which is a regular Xcode project with only Swift classes and some view controllers. We want to make this available as closed source. So I'm hoping that including this pod in a Cocoa Touch Framework would still make all public functions of its pods available to the user.
If there are other suggestions, they are welcome!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so all the problems I had with setting this up seemed to be Xcode-related.
Basically what I did to get this working is the following:

1. Create a Cocoa Touch Framework through Xcode's `File > New > Project ...`.
2. Using terminal, navigate to the framework's root folder (the folder with the `YourFramework.xcodeproj`-file).
3. Run `pod init`.
4. Add the necessary CocoaPods to the `Podfile`.
5. Run `pod install`.
6. Make sure you close the `YourFramework`-project that's probably open in Xcode.

From here on my problems started occurring. Opening the `YourFramework.xcworkspace` worked, but in the left-side navigator of Xcode, I could only expand the **Pods**-project, not the **Framework**-project; it seemed to be empty. Building didn't work either.
To solve this (So, just the regular steps to solve Xcode problems):

1. Close Xcode.
2. Delete derived data.
3. Open the `YourFramework.xcworkspace` again.
4. Clean the build folder.

Now it maybe builds, or not. In my case it didn't and got 100s of problems related to the Swift language being unavailable. I created a framework without any source files, just imported CocoaPods. To solve this create a Swift file in the framework which imports at least `Foundation`.

Now it should build.

Answer (score 0):

The first point I got is you used `.xcodeproj` after pod installation. Please note that once you install pods there is one more file is created with an extension `.xcworkspace` you need to use this file to open project and your future work should be done in this file.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of this indeed. The thing is that when I opened the `.xcworkspace`, the Pods-project was expandable, but the actual project wasn't (just the name only). It seemed that after restarting Xcode a few times and cleaning everything, it worked. So I think I got this solved.

Now I got conflicting names between the CocoaPod's name (one of the pods being imported) and the framework/project's name. So I cannot use `import mycocoapod`, because it things we import self.